# What is the difference between Azure Active Directory and Azure Active Directory Domain Services?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I'm working into syncing our on-premise Active Directory with Azure Active Directory. However when I look for documents and tutorials, Azure AD Domain Services topics keep coming up.

What is the difference between Azure AD and Azure AD Domain Services?

Answer (score 1):

[**Azure Active Directory**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-whatis) meant to be a secure authentication store, which contain users and group.AAD is a cloud-based identity management store for modern applications. AAD allows you to create users, groups, and applications that work with modern authentication mechanisms like SAML and OAuth.

[**Azure AD Domain Services**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-domain-services/overview) meant for If you need more than just user management, then it is possible to extend Azure AD to offer more AD based services using Azure AD Domain Services. AAD DS is an Azure product that you enable on your virtual network which deploys two domain controllers. They are managed by Microsoft and synchronized with your Azure AD tenant

Comment: Another way to look at it: AAD is about internet friendly auth protocols (OIDC, SAML, WSFed), while AAD DS is about trusted network protocols (Kerberos).